# undefined reference in linking against C++ library

Tags: c++, static, linker

I write a C++ library and when linking against the library the symbols in it cannot be found. Here's what I've got:

a.cpp:

```
void zak()
{
}
```

test.cpp:

```
extern void zak();

int main(int argc, const char ** argv)
{
    zak();
}
```

Makefile:

```
all:
    g++ -c -o a.o a.cpp
    ar r libzak.a a.o
    g++ -L. -lzak test.cpp -o test
```

Here is what make says on my (Linux Mint 13) box:

```
g++ -c -o a.o a.cpp
ar r libzak.a a.o
g++ -L. -lzak test.cpp -o test
/tmp/ccC4cnLV.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `zak()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I am sure I am missing something obvious, but what is it?

Comment: We can kinda work it out from the title of the question, but could you please edit the question itself with the precise error messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Link order matters.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/367273) Put `-lzak` after `test.cpp` on the link line.

Answer (score 0):

I think that -l is for shared libraries (.so). Try this: g++ libzak.a test.cpp -o test

Comment: `-l` is for both static and shared libraries.